# Vector as input to Fortran procedure, with each element separate argument

Tags: fortran, arguments

I was wondering if there is a way in Fortran to do something like this:

```
program test 
real(kind=4),dimension(2) :: vector

vector(1)=3
vector(2)=4

print *, func(vector)
end program test

FUNCTION func(x,y)
func=x+y
END FUNCTION func
```

That is to use a vector as input for a function in such a way that the function `func` automatically gets `vector(1)` as `x` and `vector(2)` as `y`.

Comment: No, Fortran won't automatically unravel a rank-1 array into a sequence of arguments.  If you can come up with a (more) convincing use-case we might be able to suggest how to implement it.

Comment: Please show us what you actually want to do. This looks like an *XY problem*. It is hard to see why would you want to do something shown in your code. But the question to your present question is just **no**, it is not possible. I believe the compiler told you that as well.

Comment: And also keep in mind generics: it could be that `func([1,2])` and `func(1,2)` both match specifics, so which would you expect to be referenced?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well defined and although it is probably completely against the fundamental axioms of SO I propose a brief "advice oriented" answer.

Fortran admits several "styles", including (except for the handling of arrays) the one in your example where functions are defined without context and are expected to be found at link time.

My advice is to familiarize yourself with modern Fortran. There are some good resources, among which:

1. http://www.fortran90.org/
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features
3. http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/Fortran/index.html
4. http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/HomePage

The most relevant update that you need is to define your function in a module or to "contain" it within the program. I show the appropriate example below:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: rk = selected_real_kind(6)

  real(kind=rk),dimension(2) :: vector

  vector(1)=3
  vector(2)=4

  print *, func(vector)

contains

  function func(x)
    real(kind=rk), intent(in) :: x(:)
    real(kind=rk) :: func

    func = x(1) + x(2)

  end function func

end program test
```

The changes I made:

1. Start your code with `implicit none`. This is considered mandatory for any new code as it prevents the compiler to "magically" assing the variable types if you omit a declaration or make a typo in a variable name.
2. Use a named constant based on the `selected_real_kind` intrinsic.
3. Place the function "in" the program, after the `contains` section. This allows the compiler to check that you call the function properly.
4. Use an "assumed shape" array for the argument of the function.
5. Declare properly the arguments of the function and the function itself.

You could consider: using two arguments, as you tried at first, but you must call the function as `func(vector(1), vector(2))`, pass the vector but use the `sum` intrisic as `func = sum(x)` (where x is an array).

Comment: It's hard to see this as an answer (as you admit).  While there may be good advice in here the only part that looks at the question is "You could consider: using two arguments, as you tried at first, but you must call the function as func(vector(1), vector(2))" - the question is precisely about that and avoiding it.

Comment: I am well aware of this. On the other hand, SO comes up quite high in web search rankings and I though it would useful if this type of vaguely defined questions results in some useful information in the end.